# Converting string to number with decimal places if the number isn't whole

Tags: javascript, php

This is both a PHP and JS question.

I'm getting  bunch of prices from an API that returns them as strings.

"62.50", "16.67", "150.00"

What I need to do is, using PHP, convert these into a) a number/int if the numbers after decimal points are 00 and b) keep the 0 where it's one single decimal 0.

"62.50" => 62.50
"16.67" => 16.67
"150.00" => 150

Then what I'll do is, using JS, include the currency.

```
addCurrency: function(price, currencyCode) {
        return parseFloat(price).toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
            style: 'currency', currency: currencyCode, minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    }
```

I've tried so many variations with the price `floatvar`, `(float)` etc but the only issue is "62.50" becomes 62.5

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does that mean that if it has a single trailing 0, then it should remain a string? And in all other cases become number/int/float?

Comment: Ideally these should all be numbers/int/floats so I can do some arithmetic with. I honestly didn't think this would be an issue I'd have. Surely this is just currency with or without the double 00?

Comment: in number world 150.00, 150.0 and 150 are all the same thing. The difference is in their visual representation (i.e. conversion to string basically). So neither in JS, nor in PHP you cannot force the number to have 150.0 and not 150.
I think you should go ahead with your arithmetic without caring about decimals, and only format the result as a string in any format you like. Removing or adding trailing zeros will be a matter of string manipulation

Comment: @mkilmanas Yeah I liked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addCurrency: function(price, currencyCode) {
        return parseFloat(price).toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
            style: 'currency', currency: currencyCode, minimumFractionDigits: Number.isInteger(parseFloat(price)) ? 0 : 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    }
```

Set the `minimumFractionDigits` to `Number.isInteger(parseFloat(price)) ? 0 : 2` and this will make it work

Comment: Sorry this returns "150.00" as 150.00 rather than 150

Comment: Sorry Just updated the answer, I was thinking your intention was to get 5.00 from 5

Comment: Here is the [result](https://i.imgur.com/fhv9z6J.png) @JohnthePainter

Comment: Yeah but 150.00 becomes 150.00 not 150

Comment: Updated @JohnthePainter

Comment: This is nice! A combination of @mkilmanas's comment and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

custom modifier
You can try it

```js
const result = ['62.50', '150.00'].map(el => {
    if(el.split('.')[1] === '00') {
    return el.split('.')[0]
}
return el;
})
console.log(result)
```

Returns number:

```
const result = ['62.50', '150.00'].map(el => {
    if(el.split('.')[1] === '00') {
    return Number(el.split('.')[0])
}
return Number(el);
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Sure BUT why does this require a custom modifier? Why doesn't PHP or JS have this ability out of the box?

Comment: I understand you. But there no such methods that can handle your case.

Comment: Seems crazy, no? Surely this is just standard currency output?

Comment: Also can the strings be returned as numbers/int?